# Integrity checks on large dbs (700GB)

Tags: sql-server, dbcc-checkdb, vldb

What's the best strategy for integrity checks on large dbs? `DBCC CHECKDB (DB Name)` would probably take over 24 hours and the largest table, being 532GB, would probably take over 17 hours.

Comment: [Consistency check for VLDB](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/)

Comment: Also see [Minimizing the impact of DBCC CHECKDB : DOs and DON'Ts](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/io-subsystem/minimize-impact-of-checkdb).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question it seems like this actually has not been run yet because you are using "probably".

However, there are two branches for this question:

- Run the Integrity checks on a backup of the database.

  - Take a full database backup of the prod server
  - Restore the database on another server
  - Run consistency checks on the restored database
- Break up the `DBCC CHECKDB` over multiple days.

  - Aa mentioned in [Consistency Checking Options for a VLDB](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/)

It is **NOT AN OPTION** to run Consistency checks on a mirror database or on an availability group replica as a way of checking the principal or primary. Since these will be running on different I/O systems and corruptions do not propagate between servers. This will need to be run **IN ADDITION**.

---

Things to make `CHECK DBCC` run faster.

---

- [Use the physical only option trace flag 2562, and trace flag 2549](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2634571)
- [reduce memory grant](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/dbcc-checkdb-execution-memory-grants-not-quite-what-you-expect/)
- [Disable non-clustered indexes on computed columns ahead of time](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-checkdb-performance-and-computed-column-indexes/) – There is an issue with the `DBCC_OBJECT_METADATA` latch that it requires an exclusive lock to run.
- TEMPDB performance will greatly impact the performance of your `CHECKDB`
  If you want to change the amount of cores your `DBCC` command, you can either use:

  - TRACE FLAG 2528
  - SET MAXDOP